# Not able to add logging when using TPL with async await

Tags: c#, logging, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have been searching for answers to this question without success, so trying here.
I am trying to get logging working in my code, within a Task.
I have attempted to simplify my example as much as possible.

```
    public void ExecuteRequestOnNewTask(string clientRequestContent)
    {
        WriteToTextFile("just entered ExecuteRequestOnNewTask");
        try
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                async () =>
                {
                    WriteToTextFile("About to call ExecuteRequest");
                    response = await ExecuteRequest(clientRequestContent);
                    WriteToTextFile("Response received:" + response);
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToTextFile("Exception from task:" + ex);
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> ExecuteRequest(string clientRequestContent)
    {
        // long running stuff here
    }

    public void WriteToTextFile(string text)
    {
        string textWithCurrentDateTime = "\r\n" + DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1) + ": " + text;
        string path = @"C:\Log.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
            tw.WriteLine(textWithCurrentDateTime);
            tw.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
            tw.WriteLine(textWithCurrentDateTime);
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

The only thing I get as output in my log file is:

"just entered ExecuteRequestOnNewTask"
"About to call ExecuteRequest"

I don't get the response logged nor anything in the long running method.

Comment: Consider using real logging framework like log4net or NLog..

Comment: That's not possible. Nor was it the question.

Comment: Yep, it was just an off topic tip to consider..

Comment: Or maybe my tip was little on-topic also: Can you be sure sure that `WriteToTextFile` works on multi-threaded scenario, two threads simultaneously creating file and on one appending text to it etc?

Comment: You are not awaiting your task, exceptions won't be logged. So maybe you are getting an unlogged exception somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does that mean a task.wait() is needed everytime I want to log?

Comment: Well, a question: do you realize that ExecuteRequestOnNewTask is now a fire-and-forget method that not waits for it code to complete? Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: Yes thats the intention, but I do need it to log along the way. Maybe I need to schedule a task to do the logging. I'm not sure what the correct pattern is here.

Comment: Fyi the write to text file is simply to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with the code:

- `Task.Factory.StartNew` is a very [low-level, dangerous method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). It has a non-obvious default task scheduler, and doesn't understand `async` delegates. If you want to run code on a thread pool thread, use `Task.Run` instead.
- The task returned from `StartNew` is ignored. Thus, the `catch` block will never do anything. If you want to catch and log exceptions in a fire-and-forget scenario, you'll need to do it within the delegate. Put another way, you cannot catch exceptions from something that has been fired-and-forgotten precisely because it's been *forgotten!*

Also, `WriteToTextFile` is not threadsafe, which is definitely a problem here. But the most likely cause for the truncated log is the fire-and-forget. If your application exits, fire-and-forget tasks are terminated - without exceptions, without notification. This is by design - they are, after all, *fire-and-forget*.

Comment: try
            {
                string response = string.Empty;
                var task = Task.Run(async delegate
                {
                    response = await ExecuteRequest(clientRequestContent);
                });

                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception logging here
            }

Comment: Thanks Stephen the above worked for me, thank you for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: Side note: I don't recommend using `Task.Wait`. Is there some reason you can't use `await`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log exceptions for fire-and-forget tasks, here is a nice extension method you can use:

```
public static Task OnExceptionLogError(this Task task, string message)
{
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var exception = t.Exception;
        var innerExceptions = exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions;
        var lines = innerExceptions.Select(ex => $"{ex.GetType().FullName}: {ex.Message}");
        string literal = innerExceptions.Count == 1 ? "an exception" : $"{innerExceptions.Count} exceptions";
        WriteToTextFile($"{message}, {literal} occured on task #{task.Id}:\r\n  " + String.Join("\r\n  ", lines));
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    return task;
}
```

Usage example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    async () =>
    {
        WriteToTextFile("About to call ExecuteRequest");
        response = await ExecuteRequest(clientRequestContent);
        WriteToTextFile("Response received:" + response);
    }).OnExceptionLogError("ClientRequestContent"); // <--- give a title for the error
```

It logs all possible nested errors that may have aggregated, by a call to `Task.WhenAll` for example.

---

Here is another way of logging exceptions from fire-and-forget tasks. It has the advantage that it's a global handler in one place, and the disadvantage that it cannot log more info about the error other than the exception itself.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
    // ...
}

private static void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Log the e.Exception, which is an AggregateException
    WriteToTextFile("Exception from task:" + e.Exception);
}
```

---

**Update:** Caveats:

1) The [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) event is raised when the task is garbage collected, and this may happen much later or not at all!

2) This event is not raised on Debug builds, [only on Release builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/throwunobservedtaskexceptions-element#example-1)!